# WPF DataGrid: How do I change the selected row programatically?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

How do I change the selected row programatically?

I change change the selected item and cell, but I cannot figure out how to get the whole row highlighted.

Note: The highlighting works fine when a user selects a row with mouse or keyboard.

Comment: Does this solution work?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row

Comment: Nope. I wonder if it has something to do with the style sheet.

Comment: To be more specific, the link you sent changes the selected cell, but not the highlighted row.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridselectionunit.aspx) page.  You need both the `SelectionUnit` and `SelectionMode` to specify how the selection is done in the DataGrid.

With `SelectionUnit = FullRow` and `SelectionMode = Single`, the user can only select one row at a time.

edit: after trying it out, it looks as though `DataGrid.SelectedItem[i]` will select an entire row. Unfortunately, it looks as if you will have to manually set the highlight in an event handler that you have to create for the `SelectionChanged` property of the DataGrid.

Comment: I already have those settings, the highlighting works fine when a user selects a row with mouse or keyboard. I need to know how to change the selection using code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the SelectedItem only gets picked up after the Loaded event of the containg element (for example UserControl). This seems to work:

```
 public partial class UserControlClass
{
    public UserControlClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += UserControlClass_Loaded;
    }

    void UserControlClass_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (YourItemsControl.Items.Count > 0)
            YourItemsControl.SelectedItem = YourItemsControl.Items[0];
    }
}
```

The code above will show the first item selected if YourItemsControl is bound to a collection that has any items in it.