# Column named ID cannot be found. Parameter name: columnName

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview which I update and fill. But the part where I search for a value(returnID) in the column(ID) within the datagridview says "Column named ID cannot be found.
Parameter name: columnName" And I can't seem to get it to work. If anyone has any help it is much appreciated.

Code:

```
   private void Application_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'registrationDataSet1.TestDB' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.testDBTableAdapter.Fill(this.registrationDataSet1.TestDB);

        textBox1.Select();
    }

    private void DataTable_Connection(object returnName, string returnID)
    {
        String varID;
        Object varName;

        varID = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "").ToString();
        varName = returnName;

        OleDbConnection OLEDB_Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Registration.accdb");
        OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        try
        {
            updateCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestDB ([Name], [ID]) VALUES (@NAME, @ID)";
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", varName);
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", varID);
            OLEDB_Connection.Open();
            updateCmd.Connection = OLEDB_Connection;
            updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OLEDB_Connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        textBox1.Clear();

        int index = -1;

        DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(r => r.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString().Equals(returnID))
            .First();

        index = row.Index;

    }

    private void Register_Selection(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=imis;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        String returnValue;
        Object returnName;
        Object returnID;
        string txtend = textBox1.Text;

        if (e.KeyChar == 'L')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            DBConnection.Open();
        }

        if (DBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length != 6) return;
            {
                cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name from name where id =@Name");
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "")));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = DBConnection;
                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "\t " + textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "");
                returnName = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                returnID = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "");
                DBConnection.Close();

                DataTable_Connection(returnName, returnID.ToString());

                this.testDBTableAdapter.Fill(this.registrationDataSet1.TestDB);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your binding code?

Comment: make sure that row contain a column with the name ID in it

Comment: @James, I have editted it to show my whole code.

Comment: @RyanGillooly does your database have a column named `ID`? The connection strings are different on both queries, one is clearly MSAccess and the other *appears* to be SQL Server.

Comment: @James,yes there is 2 connections as you said, MSAccess and SQL Server. The MSAccess database has an ID Column. It has the exact same columns as in the picture i posted

Comment: @RyanGillooly well that's where the issue is, you are querying the SQL server database for an ID column which doesn't exist.

Comment: @James, but i thought it was checking "DataGridView1" which is connected to my MSAccess database ? Also +1 for the info

Comment: @RyanGillooly nope, you are creating a brand new connection and querying the database directly. If you want to search the contents of the grid view you need to do that via the UI component - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173915/search-for-value-in-datagridview-in-a-column#13174039) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

I found that when I tested this...
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name);

The message box displayed the id column headertext as "idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"

So instead of referencing the column name "ID" I referenced it using "idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn" instead. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the column index for example `0`, instead of giving the Column name `ID`.

Comment: Please provide suggestions like these in the comments.

Comment: @RohanKandwal That is wrong please do not suggest that

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Putting an answer with "please try" is also wrong right? Where should these be put then?

Comment: This is fine. If you don't like "please try" you can take it out but that has nothing to do with it @Rohan

Comment: @RohanKandwal That post is wrong. This is not a "questions & suggestions" site. (Weird, the "add a comment" tooltip used to say that outright. It does at least say what comments _are_ for.) Please don't encourage that behaviour. Thanks

Comment: @Rohan Community has not answered. You linked to one (wrong) post by one (wrong) person.

Comment: 40 people is nothing @Rohan and it is still wrong. Have a good day

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Sure. Removing unnecessary comments. Let the meta comment produce a result. Good day to you too.