# Data grid view colomns search

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

I have a code which will allow me to search every row for a specific text. however I want to modify it so as to be able to search for a specific text in the currently selected column?

The code I'm trying to work with is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                                           Handles Button2.Click
  Dim rowindex As String
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells.Item("Column1").Value = TextBox2.Text Then
      rowindex = row.Index.ToString()
      MsgBox(rowindex)
    Else
      MsgBox("No Record found")
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: [Search for value in DataGridView in a column (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173915/search-for-value-in-datagridview-in-a-column).

Answer (score 0):

Look for a column instead of looking through Column1 using `DataGridView.CurrentCell` property:

- [DataGridView.CurrentCell @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx)

Code:

```
Dim currentcolumn As DataGridViewColumn =
  DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
  If row.Cells.Item(currentcolumn.Name).Value = TextBox2.Text Then

  End If
Next
```

Comment: @argon how did you get on? Did you get this answered?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the SelectionChanged event of the datagrid. The arguments will point to the row that is selected and then you can iterate through the cells in that row and compare values to see if you have a match in the selected row.

If you have a fancy grid that allows more than one row to be selected you will need to loop through each selected row and each cell in those rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search only in selected cells, use the `DataGridView.SelectedCells` property.

```
For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In datagridview1.SelectedCells
    If cell.Value.ToString() = TextBox2.Text Then

    End If
Next
```

My VB is rusty, just add a null check for `cell.Value` before calling `ToString()`.