# Search in DataGridView and return the position of the found string C#

Tags: c#, search, datagridview

Ok guyz , I have a somehow difficult question. 
I have on my form 3 DataGridViews and I want to search from a specific cell in one DataGridView to another datagridview and IF it exists I want to recieve its POSITION in the datagridview. [Row,Column] . What is the best practice for that ? Which method I should use  ?

Answer (score 0):

I myself don't like to search on an object that is designed to show data. The best practice is to have your data in a datasource like a List and then bind it to your gridview. This way, if you want to search something/ update some data, etc. you can just update your datasource.

But if still want to search on gridview, take a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173915/search-for-value-in-datagridview-in-a-column)

Comment: My data on the datagridviews are all databinded from a database.

Comment: @SymeonLaftsopoulos what is the reason to search on the columns then? and did you see the link?

Comment: I saw the link but it refers to searching for text in a DataGridView . ITs not relevant enough because I know how to search for term , I want to search for Array . I want to have a "return" with the position of the found cell.