# Highlight row in a DataGridView without filtering the rest of the data

Tags: vb.net

How do you highlight a row in a DataGridView without filtering the rest of the data from the view? I can filter a DataGridView on a windows form based on text in a textbox and it only shows me data that meets the criteria. Instead of filtering the data, I would like to show all the data but just highlight the row that meets the search criteria.

Any help appreciated, I’m using visual basic.

Comment: What have you tried or attempted to do so far? Anything like...perhaps, setting the `SelectedRow` of the `DataGridView` ?

Comment: How do I use selected row based on a search?

Comment: This is a C# verison. [Search for value in DataGridView in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174039/9365244). If you are unable to translate to VB.net, let me know

Comment: Thanks. Could you convert it to VB?

Comment: I converted the code but it still only shows the row matching the search. I want it to highlight it, not filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a translation to VB.Net from C# of the answer given at:[Search for value in DataGridView in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174039/9365244). I have made additions to use Named columns and to clear the current selection.

I incorporated the function in the previous answer to a standalone application. The Form has a DataGridView, Button, and a TextBox dropped on to it and the functions as per below.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        InitialiseData()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = People
    End Sub

    Private People As List(Of Person)

    Private Sub InitialiseData()
        People = New List(Of Person)()
        People.Add(New Person With {.Name = "J1", .Address = "Address1", .Phone = "123"})
        People.Add(New Person With {.Name = "J2", .Address = "Address2", .Phone = "456"})
        People.Add(New Person With {.Name = "J3", .Address = "Address3", .Phone = "789"})
        People.Add(New Person With {.Name = "J4", .Address = "Address4", .Phone = "147"})
        People.Add(New Person With {.Name = "J5", .Address = "Address5", .Phone = "258"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Dim searchValue As String = TextBox1.Text

        Dim searchColumn As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns("Phone")

        DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
        Try
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

                If (row.Cells(searchColumn.Index).Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue)) Then
                    row.Selected = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Catch exc As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Address As String
    Public Property Phone As String
End Class
```

The line `Dim searchColumn As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns("Phone")` sets the `Phone` column as the target for the search criteria.

The line `If (row.Cells(searchColumn.Index).Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue)) Then` does an exact content match. In this example, if you enter `456` in the TextBox it will match with the second row.

Answer (score 0):

```
'search amount of rows'   
 For i = 0 To yourDatagridview.Rows.Count - 1 
    'if it contains what you have typed in "yourtextbox"
        If (yourDatagridview.Rows(i).Cells("date").Value) = yourTextBox.Text Then
    'make it red'
            yourDatagridview.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

        End If

    Next
```

i hope this is what you where looking for?