# How to remove duplicate row from datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

this is my datagrid[image: datagrid with duplicate value]

i tried the following code for removing the duplicate row in datagridview

```
public static DataTable items = new DataTable();
items.Columns.Add("Backsn");
items.Columns.Add("Oprn Name");
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
  {
 DataRow rw = items.NewRow();
 rw[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
 rw[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
 items.Rows.Add(rw);
}
dataGridView2.DataSource = items;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int k = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; j++)
            {

                if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value && dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value)
                {
                     if (k != 0)
                    {
                        items.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                        dataGridView2.DataSource = items;
                    }
                   k= k+1;
                }
            }
        }
```

But no luck. I should get result like below.Please help me to solve.

[image: without duplicate]

Comment: Does duplicate row means all the cells values are equal or any particular cellvalue is equal ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash , it should check all the cells , if any one cell is different then that should not be removed.

Comment: Is your datagridview binded with any datatable or any other dataobject ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash,   ya which is binded with datatabel.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179223/find-a-row-in-datagridview-based-on-column-and-value

Comment: Instead, filter/remove duplicates from DataTable itself and then bind it to DataGrid...

Comment: If you duplicate rows in your `DataTable` better do a `Distinct` on the `DataTable`. This is [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1199956/1155650) should help you achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case, it is bounded with the DataTable, you don't need to make changes in the datagridview, in spite of, you should apply removing the duplicate rows in the dataTable itlsef. and here's you can try one way-

```
DataTable items = new DataTable();
items.Columns.Add("Backsn");
items.Columns.Add("Oprn Name");
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
{
   DataRow rw = items.NewRow();
   rw[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
   rw[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
   if (!items.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(row => row["Backsn"].Equals(rw["Backsn"]) && row["Oprn Name"].Equals(rw["Oprn Name"])))
       items.Rows.Add(rw);
}
```

Comment: your code is working perfect !!!! but the thing is cell value FL85033000EG5YYA5 is not equalling while executing code ,its wired ,do i need to covert or something to compare the cell value?

Comment: @ArchanaPalani, That might be possible because you are using '==' equals operator that by default checks for the reference except immutable types. for value equality checks, you must be sure to check with object.Equals(object) method

Comment: Thank you so much Rohit , you solved my problem :-) thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace if your condition with below code

```
 if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Backsn"].Value == dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells["Backsn"].Value && dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["Opm Name"]].Value == dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells["Opm Name"].Value)`
                    {
```

Comment: same result as my code , is there any other option to remove duplicate row from datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

If your DataGrid is displaying data bound to any kind of DataSource, you ought to try to eliminate the duplicates at the datasource before the data is even bound.

For example, if your `items` is a collection of any kind of class `T`, you can have the class implement `IEquatable<T>` and redefine your DataSource as the `IEnumerable<T>.Distinct()` values from the collection, or convert your collections source to a `HashSet<T>`.

If you are bound to some sort of database query result or table, you can convert the binding to a view which eliminates duplicate rows.

Comment: If you are manually creating the DataTable, then Rohit's code fits your needs for now. The real question is, what is the source of your data? A database query? A collection?

Comment: its collection , Rohit's code works perfectly , the same concept i have applied in my code , cell data's looks equal but when i execute in code which is not accepting the condition.

Comment: @ArchanaPalani, That might be possible because you are using '==' equals operator that by default checks for the reference except immutable types. for value equality checks, you must be sure to check with object.Equals(object) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int RowSpan = 2;

        for (int i = grdGroup.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            GridViewRow currRow = grdGroup.Rows[i];
            GridViewRow prevRow = grdGroup.Rows[i + 1];
            if (currRow.Cells[0].Text == prevRow.Cells[0].Text)
            {
                currRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = RowSpan;
                prevRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                RowSpan += 1;
            }

            else
            {
                RowSpan = 2;
            }


        }

for another column in same grid

for (int i = grdGroup.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                GridViewRow currRow = grdGroup.Rows[i];
                GridViewRow prevRow = grdGroup.Rows[i + 1];

                if ((currRow.Cells[2].Text == prevRow.Cells[2].Text) && (currRow.Cells[0].Text == prevRow.Cells[0].Text))
                {

                    currRow.Cells[2].RowSpan = RowSpan;
                    prevRow.Cells[2].Visible = false;
                    RowSpan += 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    RowSpan = 2;
                }


            }
```