# How to set Datagirdview row selected by textbox value C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `TextBox` named `txtvalue`.
Then I have a `DataGridView` with a column named `Id`.
My problem is how to set the row of the `DataGridView` selected by value of `txtvalue` equal with column `ID`.
The text in textbox ***is not number***, i just want it equal to column "ID" in `DataGridView`.
I know this way to set that but it so long, is there any fast way to get shorter not use Linq?

```
Foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Columns["Id"].Value.ToString().Equals(txtvalue.Text))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to have fast way without use loop? Any idea please?
The value of Columns "ID" of Datagridview is:
----- ID -----
   abc
   xyz
   klm
   mnz
 bla...bla
So the value is not the number. and the textbox value is equal with that

Answer (score 0):

There is a indexer on DataGridView.Rows

Therefore you just have to convert your string to a int and access the index of the row to set selected:

```
dataGridView1.Rows(Int32.Parse(txtvalue.Text )).Selected = True
```

Be aware that there is no check and the Int32.Parse method could throw an exception
Better solution would be something like that:

```
int index;
bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(txtvalue.Text, out index);
if (parsed)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows(index).Selected = True
}
```

Comment: U don't understand what i said: i not mean the value in textbox is number so we can convert like that

Comment: Therefore I dont understand the question in general. Can you give any further clarification? What is the value of the Textbox then?
Or do you want to have the row selected by the value of the textbox itself? Than I would go for a TextChanged (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) Event and select the Row by the line given above.

Comment: Value of the textbox is qual with value of Columns ID in datagridview.

Comment: Ah now I got it. There are many solution in this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179223/find-a-row-in-datagridview-based-on-column-and-value

Comment: I know that, in my topic, i use for loop. But the way i want is i want directly. Any way to do that?