# WPF - Get data in first column of a selected row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid for search results, that I want the user to be able to click on a row, and it load that customer's details. The first index of the row (index position 0) has the ID in, so once I get the selected row it will be very simple, however, I'm having trouble extracting this information. Is there a way to do something like:

```
string ID = myGrid.selectedRow[0].ToString();
```

I already have the selectionChanged event programmed and triggering, I just can't seem to get the data out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the tag `WPF`, that means that you are using `DataBinding`, that means that you have a `ModelView` or at least `Model`. Having this architecture, especially in WPF, *never* and *ever* read the data from `UI`, **read it from the bound data-model**.

Comment: So I should take the index of the selected row and use that to load the details?

Comment: No, you should have in your ModelView an item with bool Selected property and check from it.

Comment: or if you don't wan't to make a comples things have a look on this answers in SO: [Get selected row item in DataGrid WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913580/get-selected-row-item-in-datagrid-wpf), or [WPF Datagrid set selected row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row)

Answer (score 1):

There is really a very simple way to do this using SelectedIndex.

```
int i = yourgrid.SelectedIndex;
DataRowView v = (DataRowView)yourgrid.Items[i];  // this give you access to the row
string s = (string)v[0];  // this gives you the value in column 0.
```

You can also do: string s = (string)v["columnname"];
this protects you from the user moving the column around

Comment: ty for answer how can we get column name ?