# Focus or Highlighting a necessary row of Datagrid in WPF 2010

Tags: wpf, datagrid, highlight

I added a record in a table of `SQLServer with WPF-application` and refresh **DataGrid** shown a new record. For instance, I add user which has `name "Peter, last name "Pen"` and this record adds **at the end of DataGrid**. How to move focus on this record and highlight on that? In other words, `how to move focus and highlight by name or surname?`

ViewModel has such code:

```
<Window x:Class="Students.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="996" Width="1191" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Students" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">    
    <Window.Resources>        
        <my: StudentDataSet x:Key="StudentDataSet" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StudentViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=S_DEP, Source={StaticResource StudentDataSet}}" />          
    </Window.Resources>

<Grid>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="615" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StudentViewSource}}" Margin="21,322,0,0" Name="StudentDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1046">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="110" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LastNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Header="LastName" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="100"/>                
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PhoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PHONE}" Header="Phone Number" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="105" />               
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Model has such code:

```
UserBoard.StudentDataSet aRCHDOC_1DataSet = ((UserBoard.StudentDataSet)(this.FindResource("StudentDataSet")));            
            // Loading data in the table Student            UserBoard.StudentDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter StudentDataSet_StudentTableAdapter = new UserBoard.StudentDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter();
            StudentDataSet_StudentTableAdapter.Fill(StudentDataSet.Students);
            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource StudentViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("StudentViewSource")));
            StudentViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();


            //Highlighting a necessary row
            string position = e.Someth_property;
            for (int i = 0; i < StudentDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                //What do I should write here?   
            }
```

Please, as a kindness to me! Give examples for WPF 2010 as code of Visual C# does not work in WPF 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF you have to add gridview control inside `Listview`, after that you can easily select and focus particular record in Gridview.
Otherwise you must have to use DataGrid Control for this kind of stuff.

For example `(Listview)` refer this code:

```
myListView.SelectedItem = myListView.Items[index];
myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Items[index]);
ListViewItem listViewItem = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
listViewItem.Focus();
```

For example `(DataGrid)`:

```
int index = 11;
myDataGrid.SelectedItem = myDataGrid.Items[index];
myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(myDataGrid.Items[index]);
DataGridRow dgrow =(DataGridRow)myDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myDataGrid.Items[index]);
dgrow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Comment: For your information you can use second example in your case.Thanks

Comment: 1. Do I have to create ListView on the same form with DataGrid and to bind ListView to the same adapter of DataFrid?
2. Why should I create ListView cause I want to highlight a row in DataGrid? Maybe you have a link with sample?

Comment: Both examples are different to use different methods, And I haven't any link regarding List view. I suggest you because i implement it in my professional stuffs But If you want related example then you can see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/98d8423c-9719-4291-94e2-c5bf3d80cd46/)

Comment: Hey StepUp, I found out one post something like this for data grid, You can find out it over [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row) , I hope it will helpful to you. Regards!

Comment: I have tried this code:). It does not work. It creates a error.

Comment: Which option did you try ? And What error are you facing? Please elaborate.

Comment: I tried a code Serge Gubenko.

 When I am implementig the code, then the code gets error in this row:

TextBlock cellContent = dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;

What can we use instead TextBlock?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `focus on last added row` then try this code:

```
dataGridView.ClearSelection();
int RwIndex= dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;

dataGridView.Rows[RwIndex].Selected = true;
dataGridView.Rows[RwIndex].Cells[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work in WPF due to the fact that this code for Visual C#. Code Visual C# does not work in WPF.

Comment: Yes, But you can use this in WPF for selection. Actually in WPF you have to use ListView to do like this. For more details refer my another answer.

Comment: If you want to use gridview then you may have to use listview Otherwise no need to use, you can directly use datagrid control.