# Select/Unselect all Rows in a grid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid in wpf form. It has rows with checkboxes in it. I want to select/unselect all the rows with the header checkbox selected/unselected.

But I am getting this error: 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on chk.IsChecked = false.

[image]

c# code:

```
private void myDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)this.myDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        chk.IsChecked = false;
        checkboxes.Add(chk);
    }
```

xaml code is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Grid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Grid" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Grid.Column="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              LoadingRow="myDataGrid_LoadingRow"
              Loaded="myDataGrid_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              Click="chk_Click"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Name="chckAll">
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="chk"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"
                                Width="100"
                                Binding="{Binding FirstName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"
                                Width="100"
                                Binding="{Binding LastName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns> 
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks more like your chk variable is null (you don't select your radiobutton). Can you put a breakpoint and check if it's null?

Comment: ya the chk variable is going null. I really don't know what's wrong with this code:
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)this.myDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(e.Row);

Comment: To get your DataGridRow, you should follow this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row

Comment: You mean that first load all the data into the grid, then iterate through each row to find out which of the row is selected/unselected, put them in the list and then fire the event for selecting/unselecting all the rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can do what they say on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row).

For you should be something like this:

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)this.myDataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(e.Row);
```

I guess, not trying right now.