# Edit Datagrid row background based on object value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0

I have the following `class`:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrdName { get; set; }
    public int Quant { get; set; }
    public int Supplied { get; set; }
}
```

and this `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgOrders" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Height="300" Width="700" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Name" Binding="{Binding OrdName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quant}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplied" Binding="{Binding Supplied}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

What I want is that when the `Quantity` and `Supplied` properties are equal the row background color will change.
I tried it with an `Event Trigger` and a `Converter` but with no luck (possibly I didn't implement them in the `xaml` correctly).
also trying to do this from the code behind didn't work (tried to get the row instance like [this suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976506/1092181) but I keep getting `null` for the row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Binding` cannot be set on the `Value` property of a `DataTrigger`. Therefore, you'll need to add an extra property into your data type class:

```
public bool AreQuantityAndSuppliedEqual
{
    return Quantity == Supplied;
}
```

Then, with this property, you can use the following `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="EqualRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AreQuantityAndSuppliedEqual}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It would be used like so:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}" 
    RowStyle="{StaticResource EqualRowStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan. just one small correction, i think that the Binding should be to the new property name and not to `IsSelected`.

Comment: Yes sorry, that property was from the test class that I was using. I've updated it now... thanks for pointing that out.