# How to get all the row values corresponding to a column value without adding the DataGrid to XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to C#. I'm trying to build an WPF application which takes data from an Excel Sheet and insert into an `DataTable`.

The Window will be having multiple textboxes with Search Button. On clicking the Search Button, the Program should **search for a value in column `ID` that equals with Text in `TextBox`**, then **return all the corresponding row values** that gets displayed in each specific non-editable `TextBox`.

Since I don't want an actual `DataGrid` into the UI, I just created an `DataGrid` Object and loaded all the Data. After I used the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row/5483614#5483614):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    TextBlock cellContent = dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
    if (cellContent != null && cellContent.Text.Equals(textBox1.Text))
    {
        object item = dataGrid.Items[i];
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
        row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        break;
    }
}
```

But the above code doesn't work unless I add an `DataGrid` to XAML and fill it up. Most of the solutions I found are requiring me to add it to the XAML. Thought of posting it as a new question. Kindly help me.

PS: I already built this application in VB.NET (It was not so tough) Now I want to move over to C#.

Comment: If you don't need the GUI portion at all, use a `DataTable` or `DataSet`.  This does NOT require doing anything in XAML.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I have an DataTable indeed but was unable to find an code that could do such task. Can you help me out?

Comment: You can simply iterate `DataTable.Rows` which is of type `DataRow` much like you're already doing.  And you can iterate over the columns using `DataRow.ItemArray` which are all the columns in that row.  Once you find a match, you already have the row.

Comment: Can you post an code to it? To help me get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have a `DataTable` called `myData`.  This will search only the column called "ID" for a match.

```
DataRow match = null;
foreach (DataRow row in myData.Rows)
{
    object cell = row["ID"];
    if (cell != null && cell.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
    {
        match = row;
        break;
    }
}
if (match != null)
{
    //You have found a row that contains the search text
    //Do whatever you want with it here
}
else
    //No match found
```

Or you can use LINQ:

```
DataRow match = myData.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(x => x["ID"] == textBox1.Text);
if (match != null)
    //Here's your row
else
    //No match found
```

Comment: Thank you. I shall give it a try.

Comment: It working great. Thank you so much :) 

But seems like it's searching in the whole DataGrid ( Because of Rows ). Isn't there anyway to search only in the Column "ID" as it can be more faster.

Comment: @Dante123 My answer has been updated to only search the "ID" column