# WPF DataGrid populates after window loaded but how to select specific row, after load

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I have `DataGrid` with `DataContext` set to a `DataTable`, and is loaded via `FillJobsGrid()` when `Window_Loaded`. This works OK, but I wanted to be able to select a specific item when launching via a command line, the args part works without an issue, just 2 args with a switch and a value. The value is the Id of a row in the `JobsGrid`, what I cant see is how to select this row. before running `BackUpSelectedClicked()`
For inspiration amongst many other pages I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976087/wpf-datagrid-set-selected-row) but which ever way I approach this I have never got a `datagrid.Items.count`. I guess this is about which event to run my code from. 
Before the mod I had:

```cs
private void FillJobsGrid()
{
    using (MySqlClientWrapper db = new MySqlClientWrapper(MyConnString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM backupjobs";
        SetJobsTable(db.GetDataTable(sql));
        JobsGrid.DataContext = GetJobsTable();
    }

}
```

The code I was hoping would do the trick was:

```cs
if (RunFromCommandLine)
{
    foreach (DataRowView job in JobsGrid.Items)
    {
        if (job != null)
        {
            DataRow jobRow = job.Row;
            long id = Convert.ToInt32(jobRow["Id"]);

            if (Convert.ToInt32(CommandLineJobId) == id)
            {
                JobsGrid.SelectedItem = job;
            }
        }
    }
    BackUpSelectedClicked();
}
```

I have tried inserting it in `FillJobsGrid`, and placing it in `DataGrid.DataContextChanged`, `Initialised`, `Loaded` etc. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please check that this condition evaluates to `true`: `if (Convert.ToInt32(CommandLineJobId) == id)`.

Comment: Yes this was an error - it should have been ToInt64, but the problem is that the foreach loop is never walked as JobsGrid.Items.Count == 0

Comment: How are you initializng `JobsGrid.ItemsSource`? Can you verify that you get items from the database and also the `DataTable` which I assume is the data source is also not empty?

Comment: `This works OK`: does your ``DataGrid`` actually display the items you want? It's not clear what it means.

Comment: Don't assign the data source to the `DataContext`. Rather assign it to the `ItemsSource`: `JobsGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable`. Then the `Items` collection should contain the expected data.

Comment: @BionicCode JobsGrid.ItemsSource = GetJobsTable(); gives error cannot explicitly convert type DataTable to IEnumerable. Data asssignment works fine DataContext.Rows.Count shows 3 - it displays in the grid too.

Comment: @CorentinPane yes the display is fine, just cant programatically select because JobsGrid.Items.Count == 0 - obviously need other method or I am to early?

Comment: Yes, call `JobsGrid.ItemsSource = GetJobsTable().DefaultView` instead

Comment: @BionicCode DefaultView ... I'm very rusty. Moving forward again and appreciate your help, but exiting the foreach I get another error - "Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'." This is after iterating the loop and before jumping to next line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Change your loop to: `foreach (DataRowView job in JobsGrid.Items.OfType<DataRowView>())`

Comment: Not to worry - New Item row is the issue - Set CanUserAddRows="False" rather than filtering out the iteration. Thanks @BionicCode

Comment: As you wish. The first item in the collection is the placeholder row which is not a `DataRowView`. `CanUserAddRows="False"` will remove this row.